# A text book on the theory of harmonic integrals on complete Kähler manifolds

Tags: complex-geometry

I'm looking for a text book which has detailed explanations on the subject.
If you know it, please let me know.
Since I don't have an easy access to a university library, I prefer a book which can be bought(and not so expensive) in an online bookstore like Amazon. Of course, free downloadable books are welcome!
Thanks.

**EDIT**
I'm particularly interested in the theory of harmonic integrals on non-compact complete Kähler manifolds.

Comment: I believe this is called "Hodge theory" today. You'll find a wealth of survey articles and books by googling this term. For recent books, "Complex geometry" by D. Huybrechts is a good introduction, "Hodge theory" by C. Voisin is excellent, and for all the details see J.-P. Demailly's "Complex analytic and differential geometry" (available for free on his website). You may want to start by considering the compact case; there exists a Hodge theory on non-compact manifolds, but there are additional technical difficulties to overcome.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'd like to know the theory of harmonic integrals(or Hodge theory) of non-compact 
complete Kähler manifolds. I'm sorry I didn't make my question clear enough.


Comment: Ok. Then try Chapter 8 of Demailly's book (p. 367 seems particularily relevant to your interests) and google $L^2$ cohomology and Hodge theory. Know also that there exists a "mixed Hodge theory", that tries to explain the geometry of a "compactifyable" manifold, or what one gets by removing a hypersurface (or less) from a compact manifold. Both, or a mix of the two, may be what you seek.

Comment: I found what I was looking for in the Demailly's book.
Thank you so much.